# Xamarin forms: Issue with creating Distribution Certificate and .p12 File

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, distribution

I follow the below blog for creating the distribution certificate and .p12 file but stuck on the final steps.
https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File

I am stuck on the 13th step. I uploaded the CSR file and downloaded the .cer file to my machine, but I can't install it on the Keychain access. When I double click on the .cer file, keychain access folder is opening but my certificate is not showing there. Below is the screenshot of keychain access folder when double click the .cer file.

[image]

**How can I solve this issue? Where I need to upload the .p12 file? Is there any additional steps for creating the ipa file in xamarin forms?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if u have created certificate correctly then it should add in your keychain after clicking on it. Please try to recreate them and add them again. also check

Comment: also check it in My Certificates.

Comment: Did you check if the certificate is showing in login?

Comment: @MRizwan33 My certificate folder is empty

Comment: @Ramya Wowwww, In login certificate is showing, thank you...

Comment: @Ramya Please post your answer

Comment: @Ramya I successfully exported the .p12 file ,On where I need to upload this in developer.apple.com

Comment: @SreejithSree You don't have to upload it anywhere. Are you trying to use the certificate for PushNotification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the login in your Keychain Access for the certificate.

Comment: For uploading my ios app to the app store I created this distribution profile and .p12 file. In the blog the .p12 file is uploading to somewhere, I didn't get that part.

Comment: When I try to create the ipa file, I got the following error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com. (Business_App.iOS)

Comment: You don't have to upload the .p12 file. Did you create app Id and  Provisioning profile for submitting the app to Appstore? You need to mention the bundle id in your project's info.plist same as the one you use for creating the App ID.

Comment: I didn't create the provisioning profile, but I provided the bundle Id in the info.plist and create the appid in itunesconnect.apple.com.

Comment: Now I created the provisioning profile for my app and I downloaded it to my machine, but getting the same error when try to Archive for publishing.

Comment: Is there any ios bundle signing?

Comment: Did you set the Certificate and Provisioning profile in the Bundle Signing before Archiving?

Comment: In bundle signing I only found the provisioning profile option, no certificate field.

Comment: "Signing Identity" that shows in the iOS Bundle Signing is where you need to select the certificate. Certificate in the sense it just gives you "Distribution: Your Organization name".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176232/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-ramya).

Comment: Hi Ramya
I am trying to update the ios app IPA and screenshots. How can I do that?

Comment: Is that done by uploading the new IPA via Application loader.

Comment: @SreejithSree Yes, you need to create a new version of the app in iTunes and use the same version number in your build. Build the IPA and upload it via Application Loader.

Comment: Hi Ramya, I deleted the distribution certificate and provisioning profile file from my mac accidently. So now I am getting the following error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: iOS code signing key 'iPhone Distribution: firname lstname(W84Y5Q6UL3)' not found in keychain. (projectname.iOS)

Comment: Do I need to create the distribution certificate and provisioning profile again?

Comment: @SreejithSree Since the certificate was created using your machine you can download the certificate and check if it still has the private key. If it has well and good and no need to worry. If it doesn't then create a new certificate and map your provisioning profile with the new one and it will work.